# d3 zooming to mouse location, not the centroid

Tags: d3.js, zooming

I have a map of counties in a state.

I am using the code found here http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206590 to implement zooming on my map.

The original example works like this:

[image]

This works well enough, the user clicks on a state and it is zoomed and centered using the state centroid. Is it possible to use the mouse location as the point about which to zoom? It would seem easy enough, but I'm not sure how to get the mouse coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `d3.event.x` and `d3.event.y` instead of the computed centroid. See [here](http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/7770244).

Comment: Getting NaN for x and y. I printed out de.event to the console and I see clientX and clientY. Are these the mouse locations (e.g. x = d3.event.clientX)

Comment: Seems to be a firefox issue. Your example works in chrome but not in FF. I am developing in FF and using x = d3.event.clientX is working there. Thanks for your help.